# C# Detect if Mouse moves 5 times to left and 5 times to right

Tags: c#, mouse, move

Is there a way to detect this?

Imagine you would have an application where you are doing *something* and there is a Backgroundthread which is listening and waiting until the mouse will be moved - (no matter how far):

```
Left
Right
Left
Right
Left
Right
Left
Right
Left
Right
```

Which fires a trigger or calls a specific method.

Any ideas?

Comment: Yes there is, do you talk about winforms?

Comment: I would investigate **Reactive Extensions** (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx) I remember seeing some examples where event sequences where queried using LINQ.

Comment: no matter if winforms or wpf and so on.. should be equal

Comment: Use global mouseHooks as described here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C if your application runs in background or as hidden window.

Comment: What is "something?"  Within a program you write, or anything on the computer?  What does "5 times" mean - over a specific time frame, or with other moves between, or...  This question needs a lot more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't see, from the question provided perspective to use another thread for this. 
Just listen for `MouseMove` event over whatevere is it, and detect mouse move direction.

You can do that by substracting corrdinates recived by the event handler itself.

The thing here comes to decision of *tollerance* you are going to have in detection algo.

To be more clear:

*If* the  difference of `X` value is bigger then (say) `1`, count that as move to **right**, if it less then `-1`, count that like move to **left**.

Something like this.

Answer (score 2):

Get the current position of mouse pointer. Move to new location. If the new location's X-Cordinate is lesser than the previuos position's X-Cordinate then it means mouse has moved left. Similary for moving right. Every time the new position will become base position. You can keep a counter and if count is 5 do what ever you wish.

Answer (score 1):

Use the MouseMove event attached to your window. Store the mouse position each time it fires and compare the current position to the last position to determine if you moved left, right, or not all all (i.e. up or down).